# Have you got flash to play on your stock Froyo yet?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, adobe-flash

I have been playing flash videos using skyfire, but I would really like to play some games like chopper using flash.

How can I get flash enabled on Froyo? I have heard that Froyo supports adobe flash.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can download the [Flash Player 10.1 app](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.adobe.flashplayer) from the Market or by going to http://adobe.com on your phone and clicking on the Get Adobe Flash Player button.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by "stock", I have a T-Mobile G2, it has Android 2.2 out of the box, and Flash was pre-loaded. There is flash handling enabled in the browser and (I presume) in the YouTube application.

Comment: Back when this question was asked, Flash was not available on Android without using the Skyfire browser or a customized ROM.

Comment: Are you sure, Al? The question is tagged 2.2-Froyo. 2.2 had the flash update.

Comment: @Michael An upgrade fixed it. At that time, it was not available.